# Optimização de funções PHP para querys à base de dados

Tags: php, mysql, funções, otimização

Muitas vezes vejo funções diferentes em PHP para cada *query*. Gostava de saber se existe algum senão em fazer o seguinte, numa conexão com PDO:

```
function get_user_data($table, $columm, $required) {

  $db = conn();
  $data = array(':value' => $required);

  $sql = ("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$columm} = :value");
  $result = $db->prepare($sql);
  $result->execute($data);

  $result->rowCount();
  return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
```

Desta maneira só temos de fazer uma função PHP para *query* de seleção, alterando só os argumentos consoante as necessidades.

Sendo assim (não havendo senão neste *design*) até poderíamos ir mais longe?

```
function update_tables($table, $collum1, $value, $collum2, $id) {

  $db = conn();
  $data = array(':value' => $value, ':id' => $id,);

  $sql = ("UPDATE {$table} SET {$collum1} = :value WHERE {$collum2} = :id");
  $result = $db->prepare($sql);
  $result->execute($data);

}
```

Comment: Miguel se a *query* de seleção for simples assim funciona perfeitamente. Mas e se precisares de um `INNER JOIN` por exemplo?

Comment: Eu tenho sempre dificuldades em fazer uma função de seleção generalista. Já de inserção e de atualização já consigo facilmente. Embora sejam um bocadinho mais complexas que estas, uma vez que podem receber um *array* de colunas e de dados.

Comment: Nesse caso, a de `INNER JOIN`, faria à parte. Podes dar um exemplo dessas funções mais complexas sff?

Comment: Miguel tens ai o meu exemplo, mas com `myslqi_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazer esse tipo de funcionalidade na mão para mim é reinventar a roda.

Gosto de utilizar o [Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal) para trabalhar com a abstração de base de dados. Nele escrevo o código de uma vez somente e ele irá rodar independentemente do Banco de Dados ou do Driver de conexão (msqli, pdo).

Caso se interesse na [documentação](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/) temos como utilizar essa biblioteca. Segue um exemplo de uma query mais avançada no query builder:

```
<?php

$conn = DriverManager::getConnection(array(/*..*/));
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder
    ->select('u.id', 'u.name', 'p.number')
    ->from('users', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u', 'phonenumbers', 'p', 'u.id = p.user_id')
```

Além do `SELECT` ele incluí também `INSERT` e `UPDATE`, com uma sintaxe igual ao SQL.

```
<?php

$queryBuilder
    ->insert('users')
    ->setValue('name', '?')
    ->setValue('password', '?')
    ->setParameter(0, $username)
    ->setParameter(1, $password)
;

// INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES (?, ?)

$queryBuilder
    ->update('users', 'u')
    ->set('u.logins', 'u.logins + 1')
    ->set('u.last_login', '?')
    ->setParameter(0, $userInputLastLogin)
;

// UPDATE users SET u.logins = u.logins + 1, u.last_login = ?
```

A implementação de todos os métodos QueryBuilder você pode encontrar [no GitHub](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php).

Comment: +1 para o próximo projeto vou dar uma olhada nisso.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de um `INSERT` e dum `UPDATE`?

Comment: Excelente, se pudesse dava +1 :D

Answer (score 3):

Não existe qualquer problema no que indica, a implementação depende muito de cada um sendo que resulte no final numa chamada dentro das regras do PDO.

Claro que depende também muito do projecto, e para cada um teremos certamente abordagens diferentes. Eu prefiro quase sempre... ok... sempre... a utilização OOP/classes e objectos e quando implementamos qualquer modelo é essencial a sua utilização hoje em dia. Também é importante a semântica utilizada.

Mais uma vez, não sendo a melhor forma pelos motivos que expliquei, vou passar a responder dentro do modelo da pergunta no sentido de o levar a pensar de outra forma, assim e no seu caso específico da função **update_tables** faria o seguinte:

```
function update_table($table, $collum, $id, $value) {

  $db = conn();
  $data = array(':value' => $value, ':id' => $id,);

  $sql = ("UPDATE {$table} SET {$collum} = :value WHERE `id` = :id");
  try {
       $st = $db->prepare($sql);
       $st->execute($data);
       return true; 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       return false;
    }

}
```

As implementações pode variar, mas o que apresento aqui vai no sentido de explicar o seguinte:

1. o nome do método **update_table** poderá ser outro pois é importante reduzir a escrita sempre que possível mas torná-la lógica dentro do contexto. Tratar-se-á sempre de um UPDATE à TABLE neste caso.
2. A mudança do $id também é importante pois o conceito tem ordens tabela > coluna depois virá o identificador, etc.
3. adicionar algum valor acrescentado à função também é importante. Saber, por exemplo, se actualizou bem ou se sequer actualizou... para o efeito basta retornar *true* ou *false*. Encapsulando os possíveis erros que poderão acontecer também estamos a evitar muitos *try* e *catch* ao longo do projecto.
4. Num UPDATE é normal tentar perceber se atualizamos um ou mais itens mas isso depende da lógica requerida.

Faz todo o sentido a utilização de funções de forma a simplificar-mos a nossa vida enquanto programadores, mas quando o fazemos temos de o realizar de uma forma mais abrangente possível de forma a conseguirmos "quase" um texto que nos conte tudo quando lemos o nosso código.

É importante o contexto, a atribuição de nomes, a validação de possíveis erros e o retorno do resultado.

Terminando, dizer que relativamente ao código que se constrói para utilização ao longo de um projecto a *documentação é essencial*.

Comment: Muito bem respondido +1 Acho que a minha resposta poderá ser vista como um complemento a esta, como um exemplo.

Comment: @JorgeB. claramente. achei importante alguma explicação de forma a que o Miguel possa entender melhor o conceito.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não uso PDO, uso `mysqli_` mas de qualquer forma fica uma otimização de uma função de inserção ou atualização genérica:

```
/**
 * Insere dados numa tabela.
 * 
 * @param string $table nome da tabela
 * @param array  $data field=>value
 * @param array  $format %i,%d,%s,%b (int, double, string, blob)
 * @return boolean retorna verdadeiro se inseriu, senão falso.
 * 
 */
function insert( $table, $data, $format )
{

    $conn = connect();

    if ( empty( $table ) || empty( $data ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $data   = (array) $data;
    $format = (array) $format;

    $format = implode( '', $format );
    $format = str_replace( '%', '', $format );

    list( $fields, $placeholders, $values ) = prep_query( $data );

    array_unshift( $values, $format );

    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES ({$placeholders}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";

    $first = 1;
    foreach ( $data as $field => $item )
    {   

        if( $first != 1 ) $sql_insert.=", ";
        $sql_insert.= "$field=VALUES($field)";
        $first = 0;
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $sql_insert );

    call_user_func_array( array($stmt, 'bind_param'), ref_values( $values ) );


    $stmt->execute();

    if ( $stmt->affected_rows || $stmt->insert_id )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Pepara os campos de dados e respetivos valores.
 * 
 * @param  $data
 * @return array
 */
function prep_query( $data )
{
    $fields       = '';
    $placeholders = '';
    $values       = array();

    foreach ( $data as $field => $value )
    {
        $fields  .= "{$field},";
        $values[] = $value;

        $placeholders .= '?,';
    }


    $fields       = substr( $fields, 0, -1 );
    $placeholders = substr( $placeholders, 0, -1 );
    return array($fields, $placeholders, $values);
}


/**
 * Referencia os valores para que estes possam ser alterados.
 * 
 * @param  $array
 * @return array
 */
function ref_values( $array )
{
    $refs = array();

    foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
    {
        $refs[$key] = &$array[$key];
    }

    return $refs;
}
```

Fica aqui um exemplo de utilização:

```
/*********************** exemplo de inserção de um user ************************

    $data   = 
            array(
                'id'        => NULL,
                'name'      => "JorgeB.",          
                'password'  => "1234"
            );

    $format = array('i','s','s');

    $table  = "users";

    insert($table, $data, $format);
*******************************************************************************/
```